# Extracting first four digits after a hyphen using stringr

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract the first four digits after a hyphen in the following string: `extract_public_2018_20190530180949469_58906_20110101-20111231Texas`. I am using the following code:

```r
stringr::str_extract(
"extract_public_2018_20190530180949469_58906_20110101-20111231Texas", 
"-[[:digit:]]{4}"
)
```

But I get `-2011` instead of `2011`. How can I only extract the four digits and not the hyphen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regex's [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), a non-greedy way of finding something before your pattern without consuming it:

```r
stringr::str_extract(
  "extract_public_2018_20190530180949469_58906_20110101-20111231Texas", 
  "(?<=-)[[:digit:]]{4}"
)
# [1] "2011"
```

Answer (score 2):

`str_extract` is behaving as expected *i.e.* it returns the complete match.

You can use `str_match` and include `()` in the pattern:

```
stringr::str_match(
  "extract_public_2018_20190530180949469_58906_20110101-20111231Texas", 
  "-([[:digit:]]{4})"
)

     [,1]    [,2]  
[1,] "-2011" "2011"
```

Then add `[, 2]` to return just the match:

```
stringr::str_match(
  "extract_public_2018_20190530180949469_58906_20110101-20111231Texas", 
  "-([[:digit:]]{4})"
)[, 2]

[1] "2011"
```

Comment: Thanks, @neilfws! But I find @r2evans's answer to be relatively cleaner.

Comment: I agree! It's a better answer.

Comment: Your method would be preferred (necessary) when the preceding not-to-be-consumed pattern (`-` in this case) is non-fixed: lookaround doesn't deal well with varying sizes.

Answer (score 2):

In base R, we can `sub` to extract 4 digits after hyphen.

```
string <- "extract_public_2018_20190530180949469_58906_20110101-20111231Texas"
sub(".*-(\\d{4}).*", "\\1", string)
#[1] "2011"
```